# Given a circle with cente $O$, radius $R=6$ and diameter $AB$. On the radius $OB$ we take $C$, so that $OC=2$. Find the length of $EZ$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

Given a circle with cente $O$, radius $R=6$ and diameter $AB$. On the radius $OB$ we take $C$, so that $OC=2$. $EZ$ is a chord of the circle which intersects $AB$ at $C$, so that $\angle ECB=60^o$. Find the length of $EZ$.

[image]

After drawing it accurately, I believe that $EZ=10$. I tried to work this out but didn't manage. My thoughts are the following:

$\angle ACZ=\angle ECB=60^o$

$OC=2,CB=4,AO=6$

If $E'$ is Es intidiametric point, then $E'E^2+E'Z^2=EZ^2$. We also have that $AC*CB=EC*CZ$ and $AEBZ$ is inscribed. This is all I could think of. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: Hint: use cosine rule in $\Delta EOC$ and then $AC\cdot CB=EC\cdot CZ$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore but we don't have the value of $\angle EOB$

Comment: how do you propose we use the cos rule without that?

Comment: @Math Love,  believe it is the simplest way!

Comment: @BrightStar yes I think so though the first tendency of mine was also to use intersecting chords :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect points $E$ and $Z$ to $O$ and draw a perp from $O$ to chord $EZ$. Say it meets $EZ$ at $H$ then $OH = OC \sin 60^0$.

Now use Pythagoras in $\triangle OEH$ to find $EH$ and that leads to $EZ$.

EDIT: If you want to use intersecting chords theorem,
$ \small EC \cdot CZ = (EH-1) \cdot (HZ+1) = 8 \cdot 4$ (as $\small CH = 1$). Now you know $\small CH = HZ$.

Comment: Nice one, thanks a lot

Comment: See my edit if you want to use intersecting chords theorem

Comment: Just saw it now, thanks a lot for the alternative method as well, you trully are helping me learn a lot. Have a great day

Comment: You are welcome. Please always feel free to ask questions anytime you do not understand something I have written.

Comment: you won't believe it, I have just reached my limit of 50 questions for the month, is there any other way to ask questions?

Comment: Because I need the help which is offered on this site, as otherwise I won't be able to continue learning extra things

Comment: I would not know that. Are there any questions that have not been answered? You can always delete questions that have not been answered. Of course once it is answered, you cannot delete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122363/discussion-between-michael-blane-and-math-lover).